# Show Mahapps.ProgressRing when loading window in WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps.ProgressRing for my WPF Application.
How to use the control, I am trying to place the control in end of the main content grid,

```
<Grid>
    //Contents.....
    <Controls:ProgressRing IsActive="True"/>
</Grid>
```

It Shows always in top of the window, but I want to show the Progress Ring when window is loading...
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Bind IsActive to a property in your view model and set the value to true when you want to show the progress ring, otherwise to false. Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the event.